# Replace found items with regexp used.

Tags: python, regex, python-2.6

First I search for the numbers, and replace found with regexp.

Then take the changed string (?) and search for the spaces and replace found with regexp.

However I get wrong results.

```
test0 = This book id 0076 has 6782e6a
test1 = This book id 0076 has 0xef34a
```

I used following regular expression:

```
b = re.sub(r"(0x[a-fA-F0-9]+|\d+)","[0-9]*", test0)
c = re.sub(r'[(\s)*]','[^\s"]*',b)
```

My output:

```
test0
b = This book id [0-9]* has [0-9]*e[0-9]*a
c = This[^\s]*book[^\s]*id[^\s]*[0-9][^\s]*[^\s]*has[0-9][^\s]*e[0-9][^\s]*a

test1
b = This book id [0-9]* has [0-9]*
c = This[^\s]*book[^\s]*id[^\s]*[0-9][^\s]*[^\s]*has[0-9][^\s]*
```

Expected output:

```
test0
b = This book id [0-9]* has [0-9]*
c = This[^\s]*book[^\s]*id[^\s]*[0-9]*[^\s]*has[^\s]*[0-9]*

test1
b = This book id [0-9]* has [0-9]*
c = This[^\s]*book[^\s]*id[^\s]*[0-9]*[^\s]*has[^\s]*[0-9]*
```

Comment: You provided what you have, you did not provide what you want. Must we guess?

Comment: `str` is clear, as you have no `0x` before your hex number.

Comment: The last 4 lines of b and c result i want...

Comment: BTW: Don't use `str` as variable name, as it shadows the built-in `str()` function/type.

Comment: Why are you replacing a regex match with another regex?

Comment: @0605002 Because i am replacing the blank spaces with [^\s]*

Comment: Although the question is poorly asked, it pays to read it through a few times. +1 to compensate for others' -1's.

Comment: Why would one read this multiple this then giving upvotes for wasting our time with an incomplete question?

Answer (score 0):

On the second read, I realised that what you miss is that `\s` matches `xf` bit in `0xf` and in fact in any hexadecimal string.

Although I'm not sure what you are trying to do exactly, perhaps you need to use grouping in re.match to avoid string bits matching hex, for example like this:

```
In [16]: re.match("(0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)(hello)", "0xfhello").groups()
Out[16]: ('0xf', 'hello')
```

*OLD*

Looks like 2nd run of numbers may be either decimal [0-9]+ or hexadecimal 0x[0-9a-fA-F]+ so your regexp should look something like this:

```
([0-9]+)|(0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)
```

However if you are in a hurry, you can perhaps get by collapsing both into a single, imprecise regexp:

```
[0-9a-fA-Fx]+
```

Answer (score 0):

The second match option in the regex `"(0x[a-fA-F0-9]+|\d+)"` matches the string `"6782e6a"` twice, giving you the output `"[0-9]*" + "e" + "[0-9]*" + "a"`.

I suggest you change your regex to something like `"(?:0x)?[A-Z-a-Z0-9]+"`

Answer (score 0):

The first regex can be `(?<=\s)(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]+(?=\s|$)`.

The second number in `string` is a hex number not preceded by a `0x`. If it's sure that only the hex numbers will start with a `0x`, then it can be `(0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)|\d+`.

There's a problem: if you don't put a `0x` before a hex number, the pattern may eventually match an english word like `coffee`, `cafe`, `dead` etc. You should put a `0x` before the hex values.

The second one can be simply `(\s)+`. When you put a regex between `[` and `]`, all the characters inside are considered differently. `[ab]` means a single instance of either `a` or `b`. That's why your regex replaces the `(\s)`s and `*`s with `[^\s]` twice.

Comment: still it replacing * as (\s)+

Comment: Are you using these regexes in the second argument? I'm talking about the first! The trick is to _find_ a pattern first, then you can replace it with whatever you want.

Comment: how? will you please write a expression?

Comment: I mean `c = re.sub(r'(\s)+', '[^\s]*', b)`. Are you trying `c = re.sub(r'[(\s)*]', '(\s)+', b)`?

And also I mean `b = re.sub(r'(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]+', '[0-9]*', test0)`.

Comment: It output is like that: This [0-9]*ook i[0-9]* [0-9]* h[0-9]*s [0-9]*
                                                              This[^\s]*[0-9]*ook[^\s]*i[0-9]*[^\s]*[0-9]*[^\s]*h[0-9]*s[^\s]*[0-9]*

Answer (score 0):

If your strings have all the same format, you can also use a positive lookbehind assertion and just select the tokens that come after `'id'` and `'has'`. Then you wouldn't have to come up with a complicated regular expression.

Something like this here:

```
>>> a = 'This book id 0076 has 6782e6a'
>>> b = re.sub(r'(?<=id\s)\w+', '[0-9]*', a)
>>> b
'This book id [0-9]* has 6782e6a'
>>> c = re.sub(r'(?<=has\s)\w+', '[0-9]*', b)
>>> c
'This book id [0-9]* has [0-9]*'
```

Comment: Okay. It's just what your examples conveyed to me. You should be more explicit about what you want from the beginning, then it's easier to help you.

Comment: I just want to replace the numbers, hexadecimal number with or without 0x after that replace the blank space with the [\s]*